# Am I underestimating how much my catlike beasts would weigh?

Tags: biology, fauna, cat

***4'07'' tall at shoulders / 5.6 ft long (not including tail) / 420 lbs*** is what I have decided for them currently but is that believable? Google comparisons of ligers, Panthera leo atrox, lions and tigers have given me varying answers...

Answer (score 5):

It depends, obviously.

*[Smilodon populator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smilodon)* had a similar height and length, but was estimated to be heavier... 480 lbs to over 900 lbs. Smilodons were pretty chunky though, much more robust animals than other felids like cheetahs, for example.

I also see figures for tigers that weigh that much but are a little shorter.

If you were making a chunky, muscular cat, your weight figures seem a little low. If you were making something that's a little more sleek and ambushy, maybe they'd be a little high. On average, they're probably fine.

(personally though, I'd try and avoid circumstances where I'd be forced to put precise figures on anything I'd imagined, so as to avoid any risk of being wrong whilst giving unnecessary detail, but YMMV)

Answer (score 1):

Your shoulder height is way too tall. [A 500 lb adult male Siberian Tiger collected by the AMNH in 1933 was only 3.5 (~106 cm) feet at the shoulder](http://digitallibrary.amnh.org/bitstream/handle/2246/3862/N0681.pdf?sequence=1).It's head-body length (i.e., total length minus tail) was 6'5" (~196 cm) long. In general big cats are much more long than they are tall. Even *Smilodon populator* probably didn't have a shoulder height in excess of four feet, closer to 3.5 feet.

The weight is also fairly high. Most big cats that are in excess of 400 lbs (i.e., big male lions and tigers) are typically six feet long or more.

The thing you need to note is that body mass doesn't scale linearly with body length due to the square-cube law. To accurately calculate what the mass of an animal "should" be based on a linear measurement, you need to take the cube root of the comparison organism's body mass, multiply it by the ratio of the new body length to the old one, and then cube the whole thing, such that...

new body mass = ($\dfrac{new body length}{real body length}$*(real animal body mass$^{1/3}$))$^3$

A 5.5 foot long felid, going off of the *Panthera tigris* specimen described by Goodwin (1933), would produce a body mass estimate of 316 lb (143 kg). This seems about right for a big cat the size of a female lion or tiger. Body length for jaguars range from 118-133 cm, leopards from 100-137 cm, snow leopards from 90-110 cm, lions from 150-200 cm, and tigers from 165-220 cm. Your cat is 172 cm.